# EXCEL VBA: how to sort rows by odd and even numbers in cells

Tags: excel, vba

could anyone help with this issue?

I have indefinite number of rows in Excel and I need to sort them (using VBA) by numbers in column A → rows with odd number in A column first, then rows with even number.

For example:

input:

23013   316710  SOME TEXT   F2

23014   316840  SOME TEXT   F2

23015   317872  SOME TEXT   M2

23016   317179  SOME TEXT   F2

23017   317526  SOME TEXT   F2

output:

23013   316710  SOME TEXT   F2

23015   317872  SOME TEXT   M2

23017   317526  SOME TEXT   F2

23014   316840  SOME TEXT   F2

23016   317179  SOME TEXT   F2

Comment: Add a helper column to  check for odd values, and sort on that column and column A

Comment: Great, I could figure this out, haha. Thanks a lot!